# Does $\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ have a well ordered subset of type $\omega\cdot\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does $\Bbb R- \Bbb Q$ have a well ordered subset of type $\omega\cdot\omega$?

I thought of taking the subset to be A={$n\cdot \sqrt{m}:n\in\Bbb N,m\in P$} where P is the set of all prime numbers, with the well ordering -
 $\sqrt{2}<\sqrt{3}<\sqrt{5}<\sqrt{7}<...<2\cdot\sqrt{2}<2\cdot\sqrt{3}<2\cdot\sqrt{5}<...<3\cdot\sqrt{2}<3\cdot\sqrt{3}<...<m\cdot\sqrt{2}<m\cdot\sqrt{3}<m\cdot\sqrt{5}<...$

A is indeed a subset of  $\Bbb R- \Bbb Q$ and the well ordering is of type $\omega\cdot\omega$.

Am I correct?

And if I have to use the regular order of numbers, does there still exist a subset with such an ordering type?

Comment: You have to use the regular ordering of numbers...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich why is that?

Comment: That's implicit in the problem. The author _must_ have intended that you use the standard order. Why? Because if you're allowed to make up your own order then asking the question about $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ makes no sense; if you're allowed to make up your own order than that set is the same as any other set with the same cardinality.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I see. Thanks.
If so, does there exist a subset of $\Bbb Z$ (with the regular well ordering) of type $\omega+1$? I thought there is, because I can take $\Bbb N$ with the order $1<2<3<...<0$, But now I tend to think I'm wrong.

Comment: No, there's no $\omega+1$ in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich what about the subset {$n/(n-1)$}$\cup1$? It is a subset of $\Bbb Z$ and of type $\omega+1$, isn't it?

Comment: @Whyka $\mathbb Z\ne\mathbb Q$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh of course. I mixed them up. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I hope I'm not bothering you. One last question. How do I **prove** there isn't a type $\omega+1$ in $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Whyka: Show that in $\Bbb Z$ every bounded set with a minimal element is finite.

Comment: @Whyka What Asaf said. Or show that if $n_j$ is an increasing sequence then $n_j\to\infty$ (which says exactly there is no $n$ with $n>n_j$ for all $j$).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - Nice, thanks. Is there a way to prove $n_j\rightarrow\infty$ or is it an intrinsic property of $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: hmm. The $\mathbb Z$ part is $n_{j+1}>n_j$ implies $n_{j+1}\ge n_j+1$. So by induction $n_j\ge n_0+j$. Now the Archimedean property shows that, erm, $j\to\infty$ as $j\to\infty$...

Comment: @David: That sounds like an overkill. Much easier is to show that for any $k\in\Bbb Z$, the tail segment $\{n\in\Bbb Z\mid k<n\}$ has order type $\omega$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I proved that every bounded subset of Z is finite by constricting an isomorphism to a finite ordinal. But, just to make sure I understand- how does this prove there is no subset of Z of type w+1? Is it because type w+1 is supposed to be bounded because it has a last element, therefore there exists a bounded subset which is infinite and this is what we showed to be wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. $\omega+1$ has minimal and maximal elements, but it's infinite.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, but then we have to show that $\omega$ does not contain a subset isomorphic to $\\omega+1$. Which is obvious, but which it seems to me is also exactly what we want to prove. And of course it's true on some high-falutin set-theoretic grounds, but...

Comment: When I found myself saying we need to show $j\to\infty$ as $j\to\infty$ I decided I must be confused. But on reflection I don't think I was. We have a strictly increasing sequence $(n_j)$ of integers. We need to show that given an integer $A$ there exists $j$ such that $n_j>A$. But $n_j\ge n_0+j$, so $n_j>A$ for any $j>A-n_0$.

Comment: @David: But that's one of the key points about well-orders. No well-ordered set can be embedded into a proper initial segment of itself; and $\omega$ is the least non-empty well-ordered set [read: order type] which is infinite, so any proper initial segment is finite by definition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well of course. I was trying to say something that might be more accessible in what one might call the present context... never mind.

Comment: @David: You didn't say anything wrong. I just think that well-orders are not very difficult to understand (once you get past that "oh, but a well-order is only what the natural numbers have!" phase). And the basic theorems about well-orders are enlightening, useful and worth pursuing on their own!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes of course. Unless it's a context where _any_ sort of abstraction is totally incomprehensible... Go buy a cup of coffee, and try to explain to the guy behind the counter that no well ordered set can be embedded into a proper initial segment of itself. I'm thinking of like the linear algebra student who asked here how to "find $\ker(x,y,z)=(z,y,0)$"; I can guarantee you the problem actually asked for the kernel of $T$, where $T(x,y,z)=(x,y,0)$, and the student doesn't see the difference between that and what he wrote.

Comment: @David: My department bought a very nice automatic espresso machine, to make sure that I won't even have to go to the other building to make my coffee. I haven't bought coffee in a while now (with rare exceptions when I'm on the go and have no time to engage with what otherwise would be considered flirting with the barista).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fine then. I withdraw all my objections and comments. Hadn't thought it through, sorry.

Comment: @David: :-D :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an incredibly easy answer to this.

> **Theorem.** If $(A,<)$ is a dense linearly ordered set, then countable linear order can be embedded into $A$.

This is really a theorem about $\Bbb Q$ itself, and then a consequence from the fact that every dense linear order has a subset isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

But to see this more concretely with $\omega\cdot\omega$, just pick an $\omega$ sequence of irrational numbers, e.g. $x_n=\pi+n$, then for each $x_n$, pick a sequence of order type $\omega$ in $(x_{n-1},x_n)$. For example, in this case, $y_{n+1,k}=\pi+n+\frac k{k+1}$.

Now show that $\{x_n\mid n<\omega\}\cup\{y_{n,k}\mid n,k<\omega\}$ is the wanted sequence.

Comment: Why did you add $\frac 1\pi^i$? Will $\frac n{n-1}$ work as well?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely. I wanted to make sure this remains irrational. And while it's probably not hard to show that my suggest works, it's much easier with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! And is there a more rigorous way to say "this subgroup is type $\omega\cdot\omega$ because each of the $\omega$ elements of form $\pi+n$ is followed by a series of $\omega$ elements"?

Comment: Yes, you can actually construct the isomorphism with the lexicographic order on $\omega^2$. $(n,k)\mapsto \pi+n+\frac k{k+1}$.

Comment: Also, subset. :-)

Comment: Too late to change... Tough life... :-)

Comment: זה לא ממש עובד באנגלית.

Comment: Actually, this is almost also a proof of the quoted theorem: Assume the ordinal $\alpha$ is countable and all $\beta<\alpha$ can be embedded into $\mathbb Q$. Then for each $\beta<\alpha$ pick a distinct one of the countably many intervals  $(n.n+1)\cap\mathbb Q$, into which we can also embed $\beta$. The order type of the union is countable and contains each $\beta$, hence is $\ge\alpha$ and contains $\alpha$ as subset. - Finally if we find a copy $\alpha$ within $\mathbb Q$, we can translate it by $\sqrt 2$ and then find it within $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: The quoted theorem is for every countable linear order, not just for well-orders.